# Smallest positive integer such at $2^n$ contains 2018 as a substring?(Give approximation)

Tags: expected-value, integers

This is what the solution says:

Since each string of 4 digits are independent, having 2018 in a string has probability of $(1/10)^4$

By geometric distribution, expected value of digits to obtain 2018 in a string would be $10^4$

So we need to see how many powers do we need to write before we reach $10^4$ units.

Since $2^{10} \approx 1000 $, we can say $2^n$ has $0.4$ digits.

So the number of digits is:

$\sum_{r=1}^{n}0.3r  = 0.2n^2$

Thus $0.2n^2 = 10^4$ where $n \approx 231$

For the last part I don't get why the solution put summation of $0.3r$. According to the explanation above, isn't it correct just to solve the equation

$0.4n = 10^4$ because we need to see whether $2^n$ has $10^4$ digits?

summation implies the summation of the digits, but that means writing all numbers $2^n$ side by side, which the problem did not intended.

Hope anyone would shed some light with this one.

Comment: Not sure what the goal is here.  Are you just looking for a heuristic argument?  Vague probabilistic arguments aren't going to prove that a given string occurs in $2^n$.  And you seem to drop the $n$ a lot..."we can say that $2^n$ has $.4$ digits"  ought to refer to $.4n$, for instance (though $2^{100}$ has $31$ digits, so this is a very poor approximation).

Comment: $2^n$ has about $n\log2\approx0.3n$ digits

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the comment.  I guess you are right about what this problem wants. An approximation of the number, not the exact one. And you are right about the approximation of n digits.

Comment: But even by the standards of heuristic arguments, this is awfully vague.  If you really want to assume that all the strings are independent (even when they overlap) then the point would be to find $n$ such that there are $10^4$ strings of length $4$ amongst all of $2, 2^2, \cdots, 2^n$.

Comment: To stress: this is in no sense an "approximation" as it relies on a serious, and entirely unjustified, assumption.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942546/finding-digits-in-powers-of-2-fast) for using the computer for it.

Comment: $2^{212}\approx6.58\color{green}{2018}229\times10^{63}$ The fact that this is close to the estimate is either by coincidence or, more likely, by choice. Half of all 4-digit strings occur within the first $223$ powers of $2$, so this 'approximation' may be close to the expected value of $n$ for a random 4-digit string.

Comment: What is the merit of the approximation if a simple brute force search reveals the result ? Even if we assume random distribution of the digits (which is not quite correct, since the last digits are not at all random and the first follow Benfords law) , the approximation based on such an assumption would be quite poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The digits of 2^n are pseudo-random (hard to predict, behaving like random except they are of course deterministic) except for the first and last few digits. So if you calculate values 2^n until you produced 10,000 digits, there is a good chance that four consecutive digits equal 2018, or any other four digit sequence. Of course it may happen a bit earlier or later.

2^n has roughly 0.3n digits. The powers 2^k for k <= n have a total of 0.15n^2 digits. You can reasonably expect a solution for some k <= sqrt(10,000 / 0.15) or k <= 260, which would have about 78 digits.

A much smaller solution (say k <= 100) or having to calculate many more powers (say first k >= 1000) is possible, but unlikely.

And as said elsewhere, there is an infinite number of k such that 2^k even *starts* with 2018.

Comment: The last digits are far from being random.

Answer (score -1):

Since $log_{10}2$ is irrational $\{n*log_{10}2\}$, $n \in N$ is uniform distributed on $[0,1]$. In particular it is dense on $[0,1]$. Thus, there is a $n \in N$ such that $n*log_{10}2 \in [log_{10}2.018,log_{10}2.019]$. It means that some $k\in N$ we have $$log_{10}2.018 + k <= n*log_{10}2 < log_{10}2.019 + k+1$$ or $$log_{10}2018 + k-3 <= nlog_{10}2 < log_{10}2019 +k-2$$ that is $$log_{10}2018*10^{k-3} <= log_{10}2^n <log_{10}2019*10^{k-2}$$ which is $$2018*10^{k-3} <= 2^n < 2019*10^{k-2}$$ In words, power of 2 starts with 2018. So, there are infinite many powers of 2 which start with 2018. If you want to find the first one ... good luck with that.

Comment: The question is not concerned with powers of 2 that start with 2018. The question is asking about the smallest power of 2 with 2018 as a substring, which happens to be $2^{212}$

Comment: If it starts with 2018 it means it contains it. That $2^{212}$ contains 2018 is an accident.

Comment: You have completely missed the point.